# Retrieve Windows Username via SSPI + CGI Perl

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, cgi, perl

I need to retrieve the username of the windows user logged in currently when he is accessing my intranet page. I am trying to authenticate my webpage using SSPI(mod_auth_sspi.so) on Windows Server 2008, with Apache 2.2. I have made the following changes to the httpd.conf file and added my intranet site to the trusted sites on browser settings. My webpage is in Perl and am using CGI.pm. 
I am attempting to retrieve the username via $cgi->user_name() and $cgi->remote_user() and also, checking for the REMOTE_USER and AUTH_USER cgi ENV Variables to get the username.

```
<IfModule !mod_auth_sspi.c>
    LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so
</IfModule>

<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/TestWeb/">
<Files Test.pl>
AuthName "TestWeb"
AuthType SSPI 
SSPIAuth On 
SSPIAuthoritative On 
SSPIOfferBasic Off
Require valid-user 
SSPIDomain domain name
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I have restarted apache after the changes. I don't see the cgi Environment variable to get the userid in the environment variables. I have searched the same forum and others and this is what they have all done and seems to work. Am I missing something? Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Got it working for me by including `Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
Order allow,deny
Allow from all` in the directory directive. I had the original files being referred to from another directory location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working for me by including Options

FollowSymLinks ExecCGI 
Order allow,deny Allow from all

in the directory directive. I had the original files being referred to from another directory location.